# D3 transition from stacked bar to bar chart only works the first time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create two charts, a stacked bar and a bar, each displaying a different dataset. But I would like to transition from the stacked bar chart to the bar chart when I click on a button and vice versa. The code I put together works only the first time, then after that when I want to transition back to the stacked bar chart from the bar chart all the bars stack on top of each other in the form of a single bar. Can someone point me in the right direction of how to transition back from bar to stacked bar? Any help would be appreciated. (I haven't really messed with the axes yet so it is normal that they are not changing).

Here is a link to how it currently looks:https://jhjanicki.github.io/stackbartobar/

Below is my code:

```js
var value = 'stack';

var data = [{
  name: "Shihuahuaco",
  value: 1067,
  china: 772
}, {
  name: "Cachimbo",
  value: 283,
  china: 1
}, {
  name: "Estoraque",
  value: 204,
  china: 150
}, {
  name: "Cumala",
  value: 154,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Ishpingo",
  value: 108,
  china: 3
}, {
  name: "Huayruro",
  value: 108,
  china: 1
}, {
  name: "Tornillo",
  value: 61,
  china: 4
}, {
  name: "Congona",
  value: 54,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Capirona",
  value: 37,
  china: 5
}, {
  name: "Tahuari",
  value: 33,
  china: 14
}, {
  name: "Marupa",
  value: 33,
  china: 1
}, {
  name: "Quinilla",
  value: 28,
  china: 4
}, {
  name: "Azucar huayo",
  value: 22,
  china: 15
}, {
  name: "Protium sp.",
  value: 19,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Nogal",
  value: 15,
  china: 6
}, {
  name: "Ana Caspi",
  value: 14,
  china: 2
}, {
  name: "Cedro",
  value: 14,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Carapa guianensis",
  value: 12,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Leche caspi",
  value: 12,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Andiroba",
  value: 11,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Copaiba",
  value: 7,
  china: 4
}, {
  name: "Palo baston",
  value: 6,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Moena",
  value: 5,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Almendro",
  value: 5,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Chancaquero",
  value: 4,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Caimitillo",
  value: 3,
  china: 1
}, {
  name: "Nogal amarillo",
  value: 3,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Couma macrocarpa",
  value: 3,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Tulpay",
  value: 3,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Carapa",
  value: 3,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Dacryodes olivifera",
  value: 2,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Capinuri",
  value: 2,
  china: 2
}, {
  name: "Brosimum alicastrum",
  value: 2,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Paramachaerium ormosioide",
  value: 2,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Brosimum sp.",
  value: 2,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Manchinga",
  value: 2,
  china: 0
}];
// data for stacked bar

var points = [{
    'lon': 105.3,
    'lat': 33.5,
    'name': 'China',
    'GTF': 1024,
    "ID": "CHN"
  },
  {
    'lon': -70.9,
    'lat': 18.8,
    'name': 'Dominican Republic',
    'GTF': 470,
    "ID": "DOM"
  },
  {
    'lon': -101,
    'lat': 38,
    'name': 'USA',
    'GTF': 248,
    "ID": "USA"
  },
  {
    'lon': -102.5,
    'lat': 22.7,
    'name': 'Mexico',
    'GTF': 220,
    "ID": "MEX"
  },
  {
    'lon': 2.98,
    'lat': 46,
    'name': 'France',
    'GTF': 85,
    "ID": "FRA"
  }
];
//data for bar



var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 150,
    left: 60
  },
  widthB = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
  heightB = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var dataIntermediate = ['value', 'china'].map(function(key, i) {
  return data.map(function(d, j) {
    return {
      x: d['name'],
      y: d[key]
    };
  })
})

var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);


var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", widthB + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", heightB + margin.top + margin.bottom)

var gBar = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .attr('class', 'gBar');



var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, widthB], .2);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([heightB, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(8)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return y.tickFormat(4, d3.format(",d"))(d)
  });


data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  d.china = +d.china;
});

x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) {
  return d.x;
}));


y.domain([0, d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
  function(d) {
    return d.y0 + d.y;
  })]).nice();

var layer;
var bars;

//axes
gBar.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (heightB + 10) + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style('font-size', '14px')
  .style('font-family', 'Alegreya')
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-0.40em")
  .attr("dy", ".10em")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(-65)"
  });

gBar.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style('font-size', '16px')
  .style('font-family', 'Alegreya');



function draw() {
  if (value == 'stack') {

    layer = gBar.selectAll(".stack")
      .data(dataStackLayout);

    layer.exit()
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      })
      .duration(1500)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .remove();

    layer.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "stack")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return i == 0 ? '#b4d5c3' : '#ecaeb3';
      });



    bars = layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      });

    // the "EXIT" set:
    bars.exit()
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      })
      .duration(1500)
      .attr("y", y(0))
      .attr("height", heightB - y(0))
      .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
      .remove();

    // the "ENTER" set:
    bars.enter().append("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      })
      .duration(3000)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y + d.y0);

      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);

      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());


    // the "UPDATE" set:
    bars.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      }).duration(1500).attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // constant, so no callback function(d) here
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
      });

  } else { // draw bar

    x.domain(points.map(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    }));

    y.domain([0, 1024]).nice();

    bars = layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(points);

    // the "EXIT" set:  
    bars.exit()
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      })
      .duration(1500)
      .attr("y", y(0))
      .attr("height", heightB - y(0))
      .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
      .remove();

    // the "ENTER" set:
    bars.enter().append("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      })
      .duration(3000)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.name);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.GTF);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return heightB - y(d.GTF);;
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());


    // the "UPDATE" set:
    bars.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      }).duration(1500).attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.name);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // constant, so no callback function(d) here
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.GTF);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return heightB - y(d.GTF);
      });
  }

}

window.onload = draw();

$("#click").on('click', function() {

  if (value == 'stack') {
    value = 'bar';
  } else {
    value = 'stack';
  }
  draw();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
}

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
<p id="click"> click here to change </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're changing the scales' domain for the bar chart, but you're not changing them back for the stacked bar chart.

Therefore, you should put this in the `draw()` section (conditional statement) for the stacked bar:

```
x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) {
  return d.x;
}));

y.domain([0, d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
  function(d) {
    return d.y0 + d.y;
  })]).nice();
```

Here is your code with that change (I also put a call for the x axis):

```js
var value = 'stack';

var data = [{
  name: "Shihuahuaco",
  value: 1067,
  china: 772
}, {
  name: "Cachimbo",
  value: 283,
  china: 1
}, {
  name: "Estoraque",
  value: 204,
  china: 150
}, {
  name: "Cumala",
  value: 154,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Ishpingo",
  value: 108,
  china: 3
}, {
  name: "Huayruro",
  value: 108,
  china: 1
}, {
  name: "Tornillo",
  value: 61,
  china: 4
}, {
  name: "Congona",
  value: 54,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Capirona",
  value: 37,
  china: 5
}, {
  name: "Tahuari",
  value: 33,
  china: 14
}, {
  name: "Marupa",
  value: 33,
  china: 1
}, {
  name: "Quinilla",
  value: 28,
  china: 4
}, {
  name: "Azucar huayo",
  value: 22,
  china: 15
}, {
  name: "Protium sp.",
  value: 19,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Nogal",
  value: 15,
  china: 6
}, {
  name: "Ana Caspi",
  value: 14,
  china: 2
}, {
  name: "Cedro",
  value: 14,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Carapa guianensis",
  value: 12,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Leche caspi",
  value: 12,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Andiroba",
  value: 11,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Copaiba",
  value: 7,
  china: 4
}, {
  name: "Palo baston",
  value: 6,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Moena",
  value: 5,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Almendro",
  value: 5,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Chancaquero",
  value: 4,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Caimitillo",
  value: 3,
  china: 1
}, {
  name: "Nogal amarillo",
  value: 3,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Couma macrocarpa",
  value: 3,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Tulpay",
  value: 3,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Carapa",
  value: 3,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Dacryodes olivifera",
  value: 2,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Capinuri",
  value: 2,
  china: 2
}, {
  name: "Brosimum alicastrum",
  value: 2,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Paramachaerium ormosioide",
  value: 2,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Brosimum sp.",
  value: 2,
  china: 0
}, {
  name: "Manchinga",
  value: 2,
  china: 0
}];

var points = [{
  'lon': 105.3,
  'lat': 33.5,
  'name': 'China',
  'GTF': 1024,
  "ID": "CHN"
}, {
  'lon': -70.9,
  'lat': 18.8,
  'name': 'Dominican Republic',
  'GTF': 470,
  "ID": "DOM"
}, {
  'lon': -101,
  'lat': 38,
  'name': 'USA',
  'GTF': 248,
  "ID": "USA"
}, {
  'lon': -102.5,
  'lat': 22.7,
  'name': 'Mexico',
  'GTF': 220,
  "ID": "MEX"
}, {
  'lon': 2.98,
  'lat': 46,
  'name': 'France',
  'GTF': 85,
  "ID": "FRA"
}];

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 150,
    left: 60
  },
  widthB = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
  heightB = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var dataIntermediate = ['value', 'china'].map(function(key, i) {
  return data.map(function(d, j) {
    return {
      x: d['name'],
      y: d[key]
    };
  })
})

var dataStackLayout = d3.layout.stack()(dataIntermediate);

var svgBar = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", widthB + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", heightB + margin.top + margin.bottom)

var gBar = svgBar.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
  .attr('class', 'gBar');

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, widthB], .2);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([heightB, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(8)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return y.tickFormat(4, d3.format(",d"))(d)
  });

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.value = +d.value; // coerce to number
  d.china = +d.china;
});

x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) {
  return d.x;
}));

y.domain([0, d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
  function(d) {
    return d.y0 + d.y;
  })]).nice();

var layer;

// this part 
var bars;

var gX = gBar.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (heightB + 10) + ")");


gBar.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style('font-size', '16px')
  .style('font-family', 'Alegreya');

function draw() {
  if (value == 'stack') {

    x.domain(dataStackLayout[0].map(function(d) {
      return d.x;
    }));

    y.domain([0, d3.max(dataStackLayout[dataStackLayout.length - 1],
      function(d) {
        return d.y0 + d.y;
      })]).nice();

    layer = gBar.selectAll(".stack")
      .data(dataStackLayout);

    layer.exit()
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      })
      .duration(1500)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .remove();

    layer.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "stack")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return i == 0 ? '#b4d5c3' : '#ecaeb3';
      });

    bars = layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) {
        return d;
      });

    bars.exit()
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      })
      .duration(1500)
      .attr("y", y(0))
      .attr("height", heightB - y(0))
      .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
      .remove();

    bars.enter().append("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      })
      .duration(3000)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());


    // the "UPDATE" set:
    bars.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      }).duration(1500).attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.x);
      }) // (d) is one item from the data array, x is the scale object from above
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // constant, so no callback function(d) here
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return y(d.y0) - y(d.y + d.y0);
      })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    gX.call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")
      .style('font-size', '14px')
      .style('font-family', 'Alegreya')
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-0.40em")
      .attr("dy", ".10em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "rotate(-65)"
      });

  } else {

    x.domain(points.map(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    }));

    y.domain([0, 1024]).nice();

    // this part 
    bars = layer.selectAll("rect")
      .data(points);

    bars.exit()
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      })
      .duration(1500)
      .attr("y", y(0))
      .attr("height", heightB - y(0))
      .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
      .remove();

    bars.enter().append("rect")
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      })
      .duration(3000)
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.name);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.GTF);

      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return heightB - y(d.GTF);;

      })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand());

    // the "UPDATE" set:
    bars.transition().delay(function(d, i) {
        return 30 * i;
      }).duration(1500).attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.name);
      }) // (d) is one item from the data array, x is the scale object from above
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand()) // constant, so no callback function(d) here
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return y(d.GTF);
      })
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return heightB - y(d.GTF);
      });

    gX.call(xAxis);

  }

}

window.onload = draw();


$("#click").on('click', function() {

  if (value == 'stack') {
    value = 'bar';
  } else {
    value = 'stack';
  }

  draw();

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
}

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 0.5px;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
<button id="click"> click here to change </button>
```

**PS**: Besides that, there is a lot of other minor changes you should do in your code, both for performance and design. As this is (now) a running code, I suggest you post further questions about how to improve it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), using the [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js) tag.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for your advice on code design

Comment: @jhjanicki no worries. Code Review is way smaller than S.O., and I'm pretty much the only active user answering D3 questions there... just tag it with `d3.js` and I'll suggest some changes.